# About variable scope?

Tags: python

I had a math test today and one of the extra credit questions on the test was

```
product = 1
for i in range(1,7,2):
    print i
    product = product * i
print i
print product
```

We were supposed to list out the steps of the loop which was easy; but it got me thinking, why does this program run?  the second `print i` seems out of place to me.  I would think that the `i` only exists for the for loop and then get's destroyed so when you call the second `print i` there is no variable `i` and you get an error.

Why does `i` remain a global variable?

Comment: I would have, it was my teacher's test.  It's discrete math so not alot of people have programming experience so I can understand his reason not to introduce too many python/programming idioms at this point in time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Devil is in the Details

[Naming and binding](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html)

> A block is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit.
>   The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class
>   definition.

Or in simple words, a `for loop` is not a block

> A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block. If a local
>   variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the
>   definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks
>   contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces
>   a different binding for the name.

So any variable defined is visible from the point of definition to the end of scope of the block, `function`, `module` or `class` definition.

> Why does i remain a global variable?

From the nomenclature parlance, I will call `i` a global variable, if your highlighted code is part of the module rather than a defined function.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have block scope. Any variables defined in a function are visible from that point only, until the end of the function.

Comment: -1: `Python does not have block scope.` .. This is not correct. In Python, a block scope is a module, function or a class definition.